Store WAL separately in Prometheus
I would like to store WAL to local disk and other historical data to network disk. But we can only change the path of the storage with storage.tsdb.path argument.
I don't know if anybody has done something like that. Thanks.

Are you sure it's wise? I mean Prometheus was not designed with such separation (AFAIK!), and sudden inaccessibility of a part of local storage might cause unexpected behaviour. Have you considered short retention policy on current instance, and hosting separate instance (or something remote read/write compatible, like Mimir or Thanos) for long term storage?

@markalex Our current Prometheus stores all data in network disk (mounted to AWS S3). I want to reduce WAL write. I've just checked Mimir. It seems it can separate WAL and historical data. I will further see how it fits to our environment. Thanks.
